# Библиотеки классов

Tags: c#, .net, библиотеки

Допустим, имеется проект WCF службы, которая использует Entity Framework.

Я хочу эту службу скомпилировать в виде библиотеки и костить на WinService.

Встает несколько вопросов:

1) Библиотека WCF службы будет использовать свой .config или уже .config WinService?

2) Библиотеки можно дебажить только через подключение к процессу?

Comment: Думаю если оба проекта будут лежать в одном солюшне то дебажить можно dll. А конфиги можно настраивать. Можно использовать один конфиг для wcf и win service, а можно разные.  А как нужно?

Comment: Один. Конфиг WinService.

Comment: Тогда просто добавь в проект с WCF ссылку на config win service. Вот так https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC625712.png

Answer (score 2):

1. Да, будут использоваться настройки из config-файла сервиса. Стандартные конфиги в .net работают на уровне приложения, а не на уровне отдельных dll.
2. Если нужно отладить старт сервиса - можно добавить вызов [`Debugger.Launch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx).

Или задать студию в качестве отладчика для exe-файла сервиса через [Image File Execution Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.100).aspx) - но это все равно запустит новую студию, а не просто включит отладку в уже существующей.

Но эти способы стоит использовать только для отладки проблем, связанных именно с Windows Service, а не с WCF, который в нем хостится.

Работа WCF-хоста внутри сервиса ничем не отличается от работы WCF-хоста внутри обычной консольки. Так что самый простой способ отладки WCF сервиса в процессе разработки - создание отдельного консольного приложения для запуска WCF-хоста из студии, с конфигом, общим между сервисом и консольным приложением.